# Ubuntu 22.04 install openssh

Tags: apt, server, package-management, ssh, dpkg

I don't know what my computer went through, but these outputs appeared during the installation of `openssh`, and I tried many methods but couldn't solve them. I hope to receive step-by-step guidance to help me solve this problem.  (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)

```
(base) jhluo@lab0:~$ sudo apt install openssh-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  molly-guard monkeysphere ssh-askpass
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  openssh-server
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 27 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/434 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,537 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package openssh-server.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libctf0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'cups-ipp-utils' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-noto-cjk-extra' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgme0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libnet-ssleay-perl:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-smc' missing; assuming package
 has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-pkg-resources' missing; assu
ming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libjpeg8:amd64' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed

...

dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libkmldom1:amd64' missing; assuming 
package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libwayland-client0:amd64' missing; a
ssuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 22942 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../openssh-server_1%3a8.9p1-3ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openssh-server (1:8.9p1-3ubuntu0.3) ...
Setting up openssh-server (1:8.9p1-3ubuntu0.3) ...
dpkg: error processing package openssh-server (--configure):
 installed openssh-server package post-installation script subprocess returned e
rror exit status 10
Processing triggers for ufw (0.36.1-4build1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openssh-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
(base) jhluo@lab0:~$
```